# scrollViewDidEndZooming bug for iOS between iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

So I found this very amusing bug:

if scale is (double) this code works as it should FOR IPHONE but not iPAD- the label gets updated to the new high quality scale.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(double)scale {

    scrollView.contentScaleFactor = scale;

    self.label.contentScaleFactor = scale;
}
```

if scale is (float) this code works as it should FOR iPAD but not iPHONE- the label gets updated to the new high quality scale.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {

    scrollView.contentScaleFactor = scale;

    self.label.contentScaleFactor = scale;
}
```

So like wt.. so anyone have alternative solution to get scrollViewDidEndZooming scale to work for both (other than having 2 view controller classes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of this delegate method should be:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView * nonnull)scrollView
                       withView:(UIView * nullable)view
                        atScale:(CGFloat)scale
```

The type of scale is CGFloat.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! When you use CGFloat everything works for both iPad and iPhone. I copied this method from someone's post in stack overflow and he had it wrong and that's how it started.